# how to increase heap of real test phone

Tags: android, heap-memory

Can I increase heap memory through eclipse or command line (on a real phone plugged into eclipse being used for debugging only)?

If not, is there an app for rooted phones that allows me to do this?

EDIT: Im testing sensor data, so using an emulator is a pain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

silly me!
theres an app for that. VM Heap Tool (free on the market) does the job simply and beautfully.

Answer (score 4):

Using a rooted phone, you should be able to modify the file 
`/system/build.props`. If you add (or create the file if it doesn't exist first) this line to the file you can set the heap-size:

```
dalvik.vm.heapsize=24m
```

Additionally, some Android-Mods like Cynogen allow you to modify the heapsize from a application-menu. See [here](https://ryanolson.wordpress.com/2010/07/13/test-how-changing-the-max-amount-of-memory-per-vm-heap-can-effect-your-rom-cyanogen/) for a tutorial.